# App Engine JDO datastore query returning stale data – 2 hours old

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I'm seeing hours-old stale data in JDO queries, and queries from the App Engine Datastore Viewer control panel:

[image: Entity in query]

.
.
.

> ### Compare that to the following, on the entity edit screen (which presumably uses an ancestor query):

.
.
.

[image: Entity in entity viewer]

I changed that value from `.` to `--none--` over an hour ago! I have no idea why this is happening and it's infuriating!

According to Google's [GAE JDO documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Datastore_Read_Policy_and_Call_Deadline), queries should be returning values with strong consistency:

> To override the read policy for a single query, call its addExtension() method:
>
> `Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);`
>   `q.addExtension("datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency", "EVENTUAL");`
>
> The possible values are "EVENTUAL" and "STRONG"; **the default is "STRONG"**, unless set otherwise in the configuration file jdoconfig.xml.

Well, here's my `jdoconfig.xml` - no mention of `datastoreReadConsistency` so it must be using `STRONG` right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>

        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

What am I supposed to do about this? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: I do think it's not on you. seems like there is an issue, as reported here https://groups.google.com/forum/?show_docid=fae072cf1c7db8b1#!topic/google-appengine/dRUabeuAoRo

Comment: This is now resolved: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15010

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that documentation is wrong or just a little out of date.

When you are using High Replication Datastore, you have to make a trade off between strong and eventually consistent operations. Global queries, like the queries in your question, [are eventually consistent](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#h.tf76fya5nqk8).

You noticed this when eventually consistency was [particularly painful](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15010), but it is by no means unexpected.

For queries that need strong consistency, you need to guarantee this with ancestor queries.

I would recommend [this article](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore) about eventual consistency.